# Adding comment at the end of tabular makes it shift left

Tags: tables

I would like to add a comment to the end of a tabular. I use \extracolsep to make the table evenly distributed across the \textwidth. It seems the comment makes the table shift to the left-hand side. How can the issue be solved?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}       
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top= 20mm,
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm,
    headheight=5mm,
 }             
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape,longtable,array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newlength\tmplen
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\afterpage{
\begin{table}[!p]
    \centering
    \caption{results}
    \ra{.98}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllllll}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{Panel A: Daily}  \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3-month} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{10-year} \\
        \midrule        
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{Const} & 0.039*** & 0.049*** & 0.045*** & 0.039* & 0.048** & 0.040* \\[-4pt]
        & (0.01) & (0.01) & (0.01) & (0.02) & (0.02) & (0.02) \\
        \midrule
        Adj $R^2$ & 0.645 & 0.643 & 0.646 & 0.980 & 0.980 & 0.980 \\
        \bottomrule 

        \\ [3mm]
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{Panel B: Weekly} \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3-month} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{10-year} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{Const} & 0.136*** & 0.136*** & 0.140*** & 1.656** & 1.314** & 1.210* \\[-4pt]
        & (0.04) & (0.04) & (0.04) & (0.67) & (0.66) & (0.66) \\
        \midrule
        Adj $R^2$ & 0.530 & 0.527 & 0.526 & 0.866 & 0.875 & 0.876 \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{7}{p{0.95\textwidth}}{*This is a comment.}
    \end{tabular*} \label{tab:var_weekly}%
    \normalsize
\end{table}}
\end{document}
```

[image: table shift to left.]

If I comment out the last row, the output is as below.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post  a compilable code reproducing the problem? We don' event know your document class, with which options.. It also should include all relevant packages.

Comment: @Bernard I've add all the packages at the beginning, as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: `\clearpage
\afterpage{
\begin{table}[!p]` is a very strange construct, why the afterpage (I wrote afterpage and I almost certainly wouldn't use it there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments look very much like tabular notes, so why not simply use `threeparttable`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top= 20mm,
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm,
    headheight=5mm,
 }
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape,longtable,array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newlength\tmplen
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\afterpage{
\begin{table}[!p]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{results}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllllll}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{Panel A: Daily} \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3-month} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{10-year} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{Const} & 0.039\tnote{***} & 0.049\tnote{***} & 0.045\tnote{***} & 0.039\tnote{*} & 0.048\tnote{**} & 0.040\tnote{*} \\[-0.5ex]
        & (0.01) & (0.01) & (0.01) & (0.02) & (0.02) & (0.02) \\
        \midrule
        Adj $R^2$ & 0.645 & 0.643 & 0.646 & 0.980 & 0.980 & 0.980 \\
        \bottomrule

        \\ [3mm]
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{Panel B: Weekly} \\
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3-month} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{10-year} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{Const} & 0.136\tnote{***} & 0.136\tnote{***} & 0.140\tnote{***} & 1.656\tnote{**} & 1.314\tnote{**} & 1.210\tnote{*} \\[-0.5ex]
        & (0.04) & (0.04) & (0.04) & (0.67) & (0.66) & (0.66) \\
        \midrule
        Adj $R^2$ & 0.530 & 0.527 & 0.526 & 0.866 & 0.875 & 0.876 \\
        \bottomrule%
    \end{tabular*} \label{tab:var_weekly}%
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
  \item[*]This is a comment.
  \item[**]This is another comment.
  \item[***]This is a last comment.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have used

```
\multicolumn{7}{p{0.95\textwidth}}{*This is a comment.}
```

which means that the natural width of the table is already almost the full width so there is almost no stretch required from `\extracolsep` to make it full width so almost no extra space is added between the columns.

You could use

```
\multicolumn{7}{l}{*This is a comment.}
```

or perhaps better just place this comment as a paragraph after the tabular not inside it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. For a short comment, it works. But for a long comment, the problem still exists.

Comment: @LeiHao you don't need to put the comment in that tabular at all, as i note in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you really need a paragraph entry. One solution is to use `tabularx` environment and an `x` column type for the paragraph.

There is a trick that I like though: make the extra-colsep *shrink* to fit instead of stretch

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{210pt minus 200pt}}lllllll}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{Panel A: Daily}  \\
```

...

```
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{7}{p{\columnwidth}}{*This is a comment.}
\end{tabular*}
```

Some other details are:

- Your (and my) use of `@{}` affects the column spacing, making some entries appear indented relative to other, so this sets zero `\tabcolsep` and uses the `\extracolsep` for the spacing.
- I changed the last rule to `\midrule` because of the comment below it.
- The comment width should be in terms of `\columnwidth` because that's what the `tabular*` used. With `\tabcolsep` zero, the notes paragraph takes the full `\columnwidth`, else it would be `\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep`.
- If you don't set `\tabcolsep` to zero, then the `@{}` at the beginning should provide it, like `@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{200pt minus 200pt}}`